# reactjs dynamic import with constant path variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dynamic-import

I faced with a weird problem while using reactjs dynamic import. Let's say I have a component which it's name is `ComponentA` and it's path is like `myComponents/ComponentA`. Now when I dynamically import it like the following code, it would work well:

```
Promise.all(
        [
            import('myComponents/ComponentA'),
            // other imports
        ]
    ).then(....);
```

But if I define my component path in a constant variable like the following :

```
//before definition of my current component
const PATH = 'myComponents/ComponentA';
.
.
.
// some where in my component class
Promise.all(
    [
        import(PATH),
        // other imports
    ]
).then(....);
```

it would give me an error like this:

> Error: Cannot find module 'myComponents/ComponentA'.

And some times if I just add an empty string to my `PATH` variable would solve the problem and some times it doesn't.

```
//before definition of my current component
const PATH = 'myComponents/ComponentA';
.
.
.
// some where in my component class
Promise.all(
    [
       import(''+PATH), // some times by adding empty string, problem would be solved
       // other imports
    ]
 ).then(....);
```

any idea about what is going on would be appreciated.

Comment: Make the module path _relative_.

Comment: Have you managed to figure out a way around this?

Comment: @MikeK, it's for a long ago and I didn't found a solution for it. As I remember I found a way to achieve  my main goal. Unfortunately because it is for a long time a go and now a day I am working with vuejs, I don't remember anything a bout it :(.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this new ES6 syntax:

```
const PATH = 'myComponents/ComponentA';
Promise.all(
    [
       import(`${PATH}`), // try pass it like this
       // other imports
    ]
 ).then(....);
```

Comment: did you try the backticks ? we can try it with space like this `import(' ${PATH}')`  (backticks around ${PATH} cant do that in a comment)

Comment: Sorry for my late respond, but this didn't work too :(.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least to have an initial literal folder string (no variable) to restrict what modules can be loaded, because it will bundle all possible files.

This is a limit of webpack. For details see https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import

It is truly a pity it doesn't recognize the `const` other than literals.